# read data from a txt file, create an object, add to collection

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I'm given a txt file with data listed like this

```
016-023
Gallon 2% Milk
10
2.49
016-043
Saltine Crackers
20
1.49
019-011
Paper Towels
15
2.23
```

I need to read product data (product code, description, quantity, and price) values from a text file, create a `Product` object from the product code, description, quantity, and price, and use the `addProduct()` method to add the new product object into its products collection by using an `ArrayList`.

This is what I have so far and need help finishing the `readProducts()` method:

```
public class Inventory
{   
    private ArrayList<Product> products;

    /**
     * Initialize the list of products in our inventory.
     */
    public Inventory()
    {
        products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a product to inventory.
     * @param p the product to add
     */
    public void addProduct(Product p)
    {
        products.add(p);
    }
    /**
     * Load the products from the given file.
     * @param in - Scanner from which to read product information
     */
    public void readProducts(Scanner in) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: 1st create a Product class

Comment: i've updated the post, check it now please

Comment: I know an assignment when I see one. You have not implemented any functionalities so far. Try to do it by yourself and if you get stuck, post the question here. I'll point you in the right direction for reading contents from a file. Try to google "FileReader Class in java" and implement the method by yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

## Note

This is just an example: the design is a subject of improvement.

## Product class

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

final class Product {
    private final String productCode;
    private final String description;
    private final int quantity;
    private final BigDecimal price;

    public Product(String productCode, String description, int quantity, BigDecimal price) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
        this.description = description;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

## Inventory class

```
final class Inventory {
    // …

    public void readProducts(Scanner scanner) {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            final Product product = readProduct(scanner);
            products.add(product);
        }
    }

    private static Product readProduct(Scanner scanner) {
        final String productCode = scanner.nextLine();

        final String description = scanner.nextLine();

        final int quantity = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        final BigDecimal price = scanner.nextBigDecimal();
        scanner.nextLine();

        final Product product = new Product(productCode, description, quantity, price);
        return product;
    }
}
```

## Program class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

final class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        final Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
        try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/path/to/file"), "UTF-8")) {
            inventory.readProducts(scanner);
        }

        // Use the inventory…
    }
}
```